# Finding a point on an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I have an elliptic curve with the equation $ y^2 = x^3 + ax + b $ in modulo p, where p is prime.

I also have a point G on that curve.

How can I find another point that isn't a multiple of G?

I tried brute-forcing by trying all combinations of x and y, but since I'm working with 56+ digit primes this is not a very feasible way to find a point.

Is there a faster way?

Also, I'm looking for a point with y!=0 (to avoid the tangent being undefined).

I only need a single point, not all of them, but I can't find any.

The numbers are too large for me to find anything manually.

If someone is wondering, I'm using the P-192 curve as provided by the NIST:

- a = -3
- b = 2455155546008943817740293915197451784769108058161191238065
- p = 6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279
- Gx = 602046282375688656758213480587526111916698976636884684818
- Gy = 174050332293622031404857552280219410364023488927386650641

NB: I'm still only in high school, so I might not understand some of the math you might find to be common knowledge, for which I'm sorry.

Comment: If I understood it correctly according to [this NSA document](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/nist-routines.pdf) the order of that point is equal to the order of the group of rational points over the prime field. This means that all the points with coordinates in the prime field are multiples of $G$. This is fitting in the sense that if the group of rational points is cyclic, then the crypto-operations use the elliptic curve without anything going to waste.

Comment: In general you should expect that (roughly) to one half of possible values of $x$ there are two solutions $y$ (and to the other half of possibilities there are no solutions $y$). This means that if you have implemented a modular square root operation, random checking with $x$:s should give you points sooner rather than later. Here
$$\sqrt{t}\equiv t^{(p+1)/4}\pmod p$$ whenever the square root exists.

Comment: @Jyrki: What does the group being cyclic mean? I have heard of the term, but I never understood it.

Comment: It means exactly that all the elements of the group can be gotten as multiples of some element, called a generator. Here apparently $G$ stands for *generator*. So in this case all the points on the elliptic curve are $G$, $[2]G=G+G$, $[3]=[2]G+G$, $\ldots$, $[q-1]G$ and the point $O$ at infinity. Here $+$ stands for the addition of two points on the elliptic curve, and $q$ is the order of the group (=the number of points on the curve).

Comment: @Jyrki: Does this also mean that N*G=G, where N is the amount of points on the curve (including O)? And that the only multiples of G to equal G are of the form a*N*G where a is an integer?

Comment: If $N$ is the number of points on the curve, then $[N]G=O$. And a multiple of $G$ is $O$, if and only if the multiplier is of the form $aN$ for some integer $a$.

Comment: I see. Is there an efficient way to figure out N?

Comment: For that curve $P-192$ it is given. In the doc I linked to they call it $q$. In general, if you have to start with only $a,b$ and $p$ it does take some work. The most efficient algorithm is by Schoof-Elkies-Atkin. The underlying theory is relatively deep - graduate school level or thereabouts. I'm not sure whether some free CAS have implemented it. Pari/GAP? Menezes' book on EC crypto does explain it, but IIRC without the speed ups coming from Elkies' idea.